# Chrome: full screen shortcut does not work

Tags: google-chrome, catalina

Suddenly after using chrome for around six months on macOS, (first Mojave and then Catalina), the (very useful) Full-Screen shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) has stopped working.

Both, clicking the green button and selecting full screen from the view options work just fine, but chrome rejects to respond to the keyboard shortcut. The other shortcuts that I use on Chrome like forward and back work fine too. The full-screen shortcut also works on all other apps I use.

Chrome version and macOS version:

```
Google Chrome   79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    c2a58a36b9411c80829b4b154bfcab97e581f1f3-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#954}
OS  macOS Version 10.15.2 (Build 19C57)
```

Is this a known issue on Chrome or macOS Catalina? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Rebooting the computer does not fix this and it is consistently reproducible on my machine. (MacBook Pro 2018)

Comment: Since there are no posts or articles on an issue that is so fundamental, I am not sure if this is a bug/issue in Google Chrome. I believe there's something wrong on my side which I can fix to get this to work. Thus, posted as a question here.

Comment: Have you used some thirdparty tool or native keyboard shortcuts to reassign it? Also, disable all extensions for isolation. Lastly, which menu blinks blue when you press the shortcut?

Comment: @ankii No, I do not use any third-party keyboard tools. I tried Karabiner elements once but uninstalled it long ago. No menu blinks blue upon pressing the keys - nothing happens. I'll try to disable all extensions and see what happens.

Comment: **1** I just checked on a fresh install and ctrl cmd F worked, so chances of being a bug are low. **2** Try resetting its settings to default under advanced options if you can afford it. **3** Also, check under sys pref → keyboard → Shortcuts to see if the key binding is occupied. **4** Also, did you uninstall karabiner using the official method :https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362662/how-to-delete-a-locked-app/362671#362671 ? **5** Use chrome in safe boot and see if the shortcut works. If yes, then your 3rd party elements are interfering.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190395/313842

Comment: Did you find a solution @AnshKhurana? I have the exact same problem; `cmd+control+F` doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: @ViggoV no I didn't find any real solution which explained what's happening. I think after a few chrome updates and macOS updates (10.15.4), it's working fine for me as of now. But it's unreliable.

Answer (score 10):

### How to solve the problem?

**System Preference** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **App Shortcuts**

Then add two entries

1. Enter full screen

   - Application: Google Chrome
   - Menu Title: "Enter Full Screen"
   - Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Exit full screen

   - Application: Google Chrome
   - Menu Title: "Exit Full Screen"
   - Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Then the mapping changed and the full-screen shortcut works on my Mac.

### Why does this happen?

When I opened chrome on the problematic mac, I found that the shortcut for **Enter full screen** under the **View** tab is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. And I happen to have another Mac on hand, while the same **Enter full screen** shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

The strange thing is that on the well-working Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the default value. It seems that some actions modify the corresponding mappings to cause this problem...

Comment: The same thing happened to me today. All of a sudden Cmd + Ctrl + F didn't work anymore, but Fn + F instead. Does anyone know how this can happen? I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled... no change. The suggested solution here works, but I would like to know how this happens in the first place?

Comment: @nemron same here. I updated my MacOS to version 12.1 yesterday, which is when this change happened. Did you also update your OS?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Chrome Settings (in the menu) and click "Show advanced settings." Remove the take a look at next to "Use hardware acceleration" and then attempt again.

If that does not work, press F11 to make Chrome itself fullscreen. Once you've watched the video, press F11 once more to exit the fullscreen mode

Comment: OP doesn't mention video, but rather full screen in chrome in general. The shortcut on Mac is not `F11` but `Ctrl+Cmd+F` :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem.

I found something very weird that might help you: press <kbd>^ Control</kbd>
+ <kbd>Space</kbd> twice at the beginning of the Chrome's execution, then try the full-screen shortcut.

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

##### MAC OS Ventura 13.3.1

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

Above command will toggle the task-bar. Coming from a Windows OS, this was the combination I was looking for to mimic <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd>.