# How to delete a locked app using superuser privileges?

Tags: terminal, folders, macos

Recently, I was trying to get software that re-maps my mouse's buttons. I stumbled upon a software named [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), which has the ability to do many things relation to keybindings. After downloading I learned that it was not the software for me, and decided to manually delete it.

However, the application was "Locked", and I was unable to remove this lock, either from the inspector or the command line using `chflags nouchg file`, which I found linked to another  post

- [how to delete a locked app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362662/how-to-delete-a-locked-app)

I even tried the sacred `sudo rm -rf`, and was unable to remove it.  The answer on that post was using the uninstaller that I stupidly ignored, and this worked.

However, I am still curious as to how an installed software was able to embedded itself so deeply into my computer that I was unable to delete it. I tried `ls -lO` which returned `drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel`. I am not sure what this means, other than the only way to delete this folder is through root. This leads me to my questions.

- How was this software able to lock itself?
- How would I go about deleting this software without using the uninstaller?
- Is this a potential security risk on UNIX devices?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are various ways a file may appear to be undeletable. Without any details on what exactly was going on in your situation it‘s hard do get answers here.

Comment: See the comment https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362662/how-to-delete-a-locked-app#comment485065_362662 *" The how of this is the installer sets the  schg and uchg flags.  http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031017061722471"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the shell script:

```
/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/uninstall_core.sh
```

or

- https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/src/scripts/uninstall_core.sh

In summary:

- Unload the kernel extensions.
- Clear immutable flags `nouchg`,`noschg` from the apps.
- Remove the files from `/Library` and `/Applications`. Remember we used sudo with the script.
- Refresh kernel extension cache: `kextcache`.
- https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/src/scripts/uninstall.sh
- Kill all orphan/ background processes if any.
- Prompt you to restart the computer.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful and I didn't know lots of these concepts! Next time ill use the uninstaller for reference

Comment: not all uninstaller are so descriptive.. often an opaque executable. Nice to know that it  helped you

Answer (score 0):

Urm, Karabiner Elements literally has an Uninstall button right within its interface.

Comment: The OP is asking how to delete the software *without* using the uninstaller.

Comment: But yet wants to use the uninstaller as the reference.  If you are going to do what the uninstaller does, use the uninstaller.