# How to create a file that cannot be removed without root permission in macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I tried using `chmod 000 <file>`, `chown -R root <file>` and `chgrp sys <file>` . But it seems it can still be removed without root permission. When I executed `rm <file>` , the command line just shown a prompt of `override ---------  root/staff for <file>?` . It can delete the file without asking for root.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362662/how-to-delete-a-locked-app-karabiner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what I should do from the link provided from anki .

All I need to do is `chflags uchg <file>`

The details of this command are in this link: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031017061722471

Comment: Pointing out that whether or not you can delete a file has to do with the permissions on the directory **containing** it, not on the file itself.  The containing directory is the one being written to.  I would not be surprised if a user could remove the immutable flag, then delete the file.