# Please help deleting Karabiner app completely on MacOS in 2022

Tags: macos, karabiner

I would like to uninstall the Karabiner app completely. I tried all the suggestions except the MacOS recovery mode one, from the below link, but none of them worked for me. I wonder if the suggestions are no longer valid now in 2022.

[How to delete a locked app, Karabiner?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362662/how-to-delete-a-locked-app-karabiner)

I get "operation not permitted" for all the terminal commands. I am using administrator account in MacOS Ventura (13.0).

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue on Ventura.

Comment: The linked Q&A has had multiple newer answers and updates to existing answers provided. Indeed this Q&A is now getting duplicate answers to those provided on the linked Q&A. I am closing this one in favour of the existing Q&A which has the same solutions as provided here.

Answer (score 3):

The first place to look is the manaul for any application.
Karabionier-elements is at https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/

And it has a section [Uninstall](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/operation/uninstall/)

Which  says

> Karabiner-Elements provides built-in uninstaller.
> Use the uninstaller to remove Karabiner-Elements from your system.

or these commands

```
bash '/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-DriverKit-VirtualHIDDevice/scripts/uninstall/deactivate_driver.sh'
sudo '/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/uninstall.sh'
```

Comment: OP commented that they are having issues with those terminal commands: " get "operation not permitted" for all the terminal commands." 

I believe it's a Ventura issue as I have the same problem.

Comment: @AshZade The commands that are shown are not the commands I show

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't read their commands and assumed they were trying the ones recommended by Karabiner, which you posted.

Comment: @mmmm: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestions before posting the question here, as I did find them in the official docs, but it didn't uninstall completely. The 2 applications 'Karabiner-elements' and 'Karabiner-EventViewer' are still present in Finder/Applications, and their services are also present in System Preferences - Login Items and Input Monitoring. I was able to turn them off but they are still in the list.

Comment: @AshZade: Can't say if it's a Ventura issue as they claim to support Ventura OS as well. If you find anything useful, please update this thread if you can.

Comment: @AshokBijoyDebnath In that case I would raise that as an issue with the authors

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable your terminal to do that operation. Go to System Setting -> App Management -> then toggle the app you are using to enable application to update/delete other applications. After doing that you'll need to restart your terminal.

Come bak to your terminal and run: `sudo chflags nouchg,noschg Karabiner-Elements.app`.

Finally run `sudo rm -rf Karabiner-Elements.app`

Answer (score 0):

Karabiner-Elements is not a good thing. Use these commands to be able to delete it.

```
sudo chflags nouchg,noschg /Applications/Karabiner-Elements.app

sudo chflags nouchg,noschg /Applications/Karabiner-EventViewer.app
```